# hive streaming with python script using virtual environment

Tags: python, hive

I am trying to use hive streaming with a python script. I would like to use python modules not installed on the worker nodes. So I was trying add a virtual environment and install the modules I need within it. I followed the process in this blog post
http://blog.iamghost.kr/post/91329784133/hive-python-virtualenv

(could not find an English reference)
However, for any modules that I installed in the virtualenv, I get an ImportError, for example 
ImportError: No module named lxml

Using the virtual environment locally, I am able to import the packages just fine.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Shell script I am using

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ./venv_package
source venv/bin/activate
python pyscript.py
```

Python script used in the transform

```
import sys
from lxml import html

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip('\n')
    row = line.split('\t')
    cleaned_html_0 = html.fromstring(row[0]).text_content()
    cleaned_html_1 = html.fromstring(row[1]).text_content()

    print '\t'.join([cleaned_html_0, cleaned_html_1])
```

Directory structure

```
venv_package >ls
pyscript.py venv
```

Comment: Can you include the code you're using that gets the error? Can you go into more detail about how you installed `lxml`, and if importing it works anywhere?